# given that $ker[T]=ker[T^2]$ prove that $ker[T]\cap im[T]=\{{0}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I feel that I'm stuck, given that $ker[T]=ker[T^2]$ I need to show that $ker[T]\cap im[T]=\{{0}\}$,
now, I know that I need to use that $ker[T]\subseteq ker[T^2]$, and also use that $ker[T^2]\subseteq ker[T]$. but I really don't know-how.
may I have some hint, please?

Comment: One approach is to show that the restriction of $T$ to the image of $T$ must be an isomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $\;x\in\ker T\cap\text{Im}\,T\;$ , then $\;Tx=0\;$ and also there exists a vector $\;v\;$ such that $\;x=Tv\;$ , but then

$$0=Tx=T(Tv)=T^2v\implies v\in\ker T^2\stackrel{\text{given!}}=\ker T\implies0=Tv=x$$

and we're done

Answer (score 1):

Take $v \in ker(T)\cap Im(T)$, then $v = Tu$. Now apply $T$ on both sides and use what you know about the kernels. Can you finish?